# Missing ) in parenthetical error, but everything seems to be closed off properly

Tags: javascript, parentheses

I'm getting the missing ) error from the following code. JS Hint says a ) is expected from the top line, but "if" found instead.

```
denom = (((theZombies[j].y + 15) – theZombies[j].y) * (mouseX – Player1.x) – ((theZombies[j].x + 18) – (theZombies[j].x - 18 )) * (mouseY - Player1.y));

if (denom != 0) {theZombies.splice(j, 1);}
```

But I don't get it -- all the parentheses are closed off properly. I've also looked back in the code and can't find an unclosed one previously. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your next debug step should be to run your code through jslint. This is how Slaks found your error.

Comment: @djechlin - nope, Notepad ++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `–` characters are atually [U+2013 EN DASH](http://codepoints.net/U+2013)es, which are not legal in Javascript.

You need to use [U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS](http://codepoints.net/U+002D) instead.

Comment: wow !! How could you deduce that. Did you observe the minute difference in widths that clearly?

Comment: @Sushanth--: No; I ran an error checker and got an `Unexpected '–'` error.  This makes it fairly obvious that the character is not what you think it is.

Comment: right.. jsLint points that out. But still it would take me a while to come to that conclusion :) .

Comment: I did a search and replace but I'm still getting the parenthetical error, and still getting unexpected '-' error in JSLint. I'm using Notepad++, so why are the dashes the wrong type and why would this create a parenthetical error?

Comment: @FlyingLizard: Your keyboard may be producing the wrong kind of dash.  To find out, open a JS console and type `'<dash>'.charCodeAt(0)` (a normal hyphen is `0x2d`, which is `45`).  Try copy-pasting `-`.

Comment: @FlyingLizard: No; I mean to press the dash key on your keyboard.

Comment: Ah OK. using the dash it returned 45. Is that the good kind or the bad kind?

Comment: @FlyingLizard: `45` is a regular dash.  Your text editor is probably acting up.